# c# dynamically change tuple size

Tags: c#, tuples

Basically i want to export some lists. Theese lists contains different columns. For example

StudentID - StudentName - Assignment1 - Assignment2 - Final Exam

But sometimes there are different exams. I am using tuple class to add theese lists.

```
exportList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(item.ID, item.Name + item.Surname, payList[i]));
```

this contains 3 columns. Is there a way to change tuple parameters dynamically?

Comment: No. "Best" (where "best" is a strong word... Using `Tuple<>` with many parameters normally is laziness) solution is to create the `Tuple<>` with the maximum number of parameters and set to `null` if you don't need them.

Comment: I would suggest you to use `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`

Answer (score 1):

In your case i would not use `Tuple`s. I rather would use `classes`, which inherit from one another, to allow variating properties.

For example:

```
public class Student // only a sample
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class StudentWithGrade : Student
{
    public int Grade
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Your list could than accept types of `Student`, which can be a `Student` or `StudenWithGrade` or anything that inherit from student.

This makes your code also more readable for others.

**EDIT**

If you really need some thing *dynamic*, use a list of dictionaries,
where one entry in the list represents a kind of `row` and the entries
in the `Dictionary<string, object>` represents the *columns*.

Answer (score 1):

No, tuples are immutable. It seems like you're not using *tuples* to what they're meant to be used.

If you insist in not using *classes* to hold your data, your best bet are dictionaries:

```
exportList.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "ID", item.ID }, { "Name", item.Name }, { "Surname", item.Surname }, { "PayList", payList[i] } });
```

Now if you get the whole item, you'll be able to edit each item as follows:

```
exportList[0]["ID"] = 11;
exportList[0]["Name"] = "Matías";
exportList[0]["Surname"] = "Fidemraizer";
```

Another option is using a dynamic object like `ExpandoObject`:

```
dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();
person.ID = 11;
person.Name = "Matías";
person.Surname = "Fidemraizer";

exportList.Add(person);
```

Since `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, you can access properties using regular dot syntax, or you can cast an `ExpandoObject` to `IDictionary<string, object>` and access properties as dictionary keys:

```
dynamic person = exportList[0];
string name = person.Name;

// or...

IDictionary<string, object> person = (IDictionary<string, object>)exportList[0];
string name = (string)person["Name"];
```

BTW, I still feel that you should go with designing and using an actual class to hold your persons' data either way...